# Ember.js dependency injection

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript

let's assume I have this controller

```
MyApp.LayoutFooterController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  formData:
    name: null,
    phone: null,
    message: null

  cleanFormData: ->
    @set('formData.name', null)
    @set('formData.phone', null)
    @set('formData.message', null)

  send: () ->
    @container.lookup('api:contact').send(
       @get('formData.name'),
       @get('formData.phone'),
       @get('formData.message')
    )
    @cleanFormData()
```

For this I've created service class

```
MyApp.Api ||= {}
MyApp.Api.Contact = Ember.Object.extend
  init(@$, @anotherDep) ->
  send: (name, phone, message) ->
    console.log name, phone, message
```

and initializer

```
Ember.Application.initializer
  name: 'contact'

  initialize: (container, application) ->
    container.register 'api:contact', MyApp.Api.Contact
```

Problem is, that I can not figure out how to set container to be able to resolve my service class dependecies `init(@$, @anotherDep)` through Ember container.

Can anybody give me explanation, how to use the Ember.js dependecy injection (or service locator, I guess) container to inject other libs or objects?

Maybe, that I'm not doing it well at all.

**EDIT**

When I looked to Ember's [container source code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/container/lib/main.js#L259) I found a solution:

```
Ember.Application.initializer
  name: 'contact'

  initialize: (container, application) ->
    container.register 'api:contact', { create: () -> new MyApp.Api.Contact(application.$) }
```

But is this clean?

Comment: I'd love to know about this too. This topic is nowhere at the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you don't want to be wiring up all of the pieces yourself, you want to use `needs` in your controller to let Ember do it for you.  I'm not sure at all how Ember deals with 3 level class names vs two, so I'm just going to demonstrate with two levels.  (`MyApp.ApiContact` instead of `MyApp.Api.Contact`.)  Also, `send` is a native Ember method that is present on all (or almost all) objects, so you'd want to use something like `sendMessage` instead so that you don't end up with hard to diagnose conflicts.  After you have told Ember that your controller `needs` `apiContact`, you can just call `this.get('controllers.apiContact')` to get a hold of it.

```
MyApp.LayoutFooterController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs : ['apiContact'],
  // All your other stuff here
  sendMessage : function(){
    this.get('controllers.apiContact').sendMessage(...);
  }
});
```

Comment: I believe, that this is very similiar (maybe better approach) to what I did. I know (or better, I guess) that if `MyApp.ApiContact` needs some own dependencies, I can mention them in `needs` also. But all those dependecies have to be in MyApp `scope`, right? What about some third party libraries? I have to write wrappers for them? Very common example is jQuery in my opinion (if I don't want to use global space).

Comment: Each controller should have it's own `needs` array.  You can build a tree of related controllers that way.  I'm not sure what you mean by third party libraries.  If those libraries are providing Ember classes you would usually `extend` them to get a version of those classed inside your app namespace.  If they do not provide Ember classes you'd just use them like normal inside your own Ember classes.